# How to save screenshots as JPG automatically?

Tags: screenshot

I want to make all screenshots I take jpeg automatically -- not png. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: 1)Try a different screenshot app 2) Convert PNG to JPEG in GIMP 3) Try Pinta (see answer below) 4) Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, this site works best with one question at a time, and watch out for duplicates. FAQ with more details [here](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but still useful: If you change the file extension to jpg when saving the screenshot, Ubuntu will not save it as png.

Answer (score 13):

Open "dconf-editor"

"dconf editor" is available for installation in the ubuntu software center

navigate to org > gnome > gnome-screenshot   and change the default-file-type png to jpg.

Comment: The recorded screenshots with this method have a quality setting of 75, which is terrible if there is text on the screen.

Comment: While the setting exists as described, this seems to have no effect in 18.04. Images are still saved as PNG.

Comment: Confirmed - works in Ubuntu 20.04. In dconf-editor: once you're done making the above changes, navigate to a different page, this will save the settings. I had to do it twice because during the first time changes weren't saved.

Answer (score 6):

Im not sure what software you are using to capture screen-shots, however if you need more control to save Screenshots as a certain file type (jpg etc) or to change where you want to save them, try **"Shutter"**, Its available in the software centre, it will give you more options you require and more.

Comment: shutter default save format as png but you can change it in -> edit -> preference

Answer (score 4):

The default tool **gnome-screenshot** doesn't provide this feature yet. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/703601); I suggest to [mark that it affects you, too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/703601/+affectsmetoo). Since 2008 there is a [patch](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=521751) for that - but it seems that it never made it into the package ...

Answer (score 3):

This is posted in 2021, and using the dconf editor is an excellent solution. There are four formats available, .bmp, .jpg, .png, .tiff.

Comment: There's no need to include the date, as the post date is shown immediately above your avatar. Also, this answer doesn't add much to the [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/635150/348964), apart from the formats available.