# How to set screenshot format to jpg?

Tags: screenshot

I am wondering how can I change default screenshots to jpg, specially  for MPlayer where default shots are in png which renders the images too large.

Comment: Are you specific to mplayer or the default screenshot application installed on Ubuntu

Comment: Please read http://askubuntu.com/questions/128855/how-to-save-screenshots-as-jpg-automatically

Comment: In my opinion, this is not exact duplicate of the question I guess, since the OP here wants an option specifically for mplayer.