# Automatically Save Screenshot as jpg insted of png in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bash, gnome, scripts, gnome-screenshot

I prefer jpg format for my screenshots as it is compact. Earlier, I used to save jpg screenshots by changing the settings through Dconf editor. But, it is no longer working in GNOME 42.

I have found a lot of scripts that can convert bulk images from png to jpg using scripts. Here's the link to the reference. It will redirect to [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/71028/batch-converting-png-to-jpg-in-linux).

Is there any way to tweak this script and make it automated so that it can overwrite my png screenshots with jpg every time I take a new screenshot?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? And are you using Wayland or xorg?

Comment: Also which dconf key did you try?

Comment: @Baa I am using Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland

Comment: @Baa https://askubuntu.com/questions/128855/how-to-save-screenshots-as-jpg-automatically here is the link to dconf settings that no longer works with GNOME 42.

Comment: What tool do you use for screenshots? Can't you just change its settings?

Comment: @terdon I was using the default screenshot tool. Well, I have manually changed the shortcuts for screenshots to gnome-screenshot and it is working.